# jQuery UI Dialog Iframe - Remove From Browser History Upon Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, browser-history

I use a jQuery UI Dialog with an `iframe` in order to provide an in-page "pop-up" for editing. Every time the dialog is opened, it adds two requests to the browser to the history: one for the URL loaded when opened, and one for setting the `src` to blank when the dialog is closed. If the end-user clicks the back button, they don't see anything happening, because it's going back in the `iframe` that is no longer being displayed.

So, I understand **why** this is happening, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to prevent it. Is there a way to "rewind" the history on the `iframe` when it is closed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $iframe = $('<iframe id="uiDialogIframe" data-reload="0" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="450" />');
    var $dialog = $('<div id="uiDialogIframeWrapper" />').append($iframe).appendTo('body').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        close: function () {
            $iframe.attr('src', '');
            if ('1' === $iframe.attr('data-reload')) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    $('a.uiDialogIframe').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $iframe.attr('src', $this.attr('href'));
        $dialog.dialog('option', 'title', $this.data('title'))
                .dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe this answer helps a bit http://stackoverflow.com/a/13706321/3032128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using avoiding the creation of history in the first place, by recreating the `iframe` every time.

**Parent Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div id="uiDialogIframeWrapper" data-reload="0" />').appendTo('body').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        close: function () {
            // check for reload flag
            if ('1' === $dialog.attr('data-reload')) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    $dialog.on('goto', function(e, url) {
        $dialog.empty().append('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="450" src="' + url + '" />');
    });
    $('a.uiDialogIframe').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $dialog.trigger('goto', $this.attr('href'))
                .dialog('option', 'title', $this.data('title'))
                .dialog('open');
    });
});
```

**Child Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get the dialog object
    var $dialog = parent.jQuery('#uiDialogIframeWrapper');
    // flag the parent to reload
    $('.parentReload').on('click', function() {
        $dialog.attr('data-reload', '1');
    });
    // close the dialog
    if (0 < $('body.closeDialog').length) {
        $dialog.dialog('close');
    }
    // use goto for internal links
    $('a[href^="/"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $dialog.trigger('goto', $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with html5 it seems there are some nice new things you can do with the history object

some [additional information from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

This is a blurb from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-history-pushstate/) so you can add some additional code to control how these loads effect the history.

1. When the state changes, e.g. the user opens an email, history.pushState() is passed state information and executed. This enables the back button but — importantly — does not move the user from the page.
2. You can run history.pushState() as many times as necessary, or modify the current state using history.replaceState().
3. When the user clicks back (or forward), the window.onpopstate event is fired. A handler function can retrieve the associated state and display the appropriate screen.

may not be 100% how too but this should get you looking in the right place.